# Multi Selection menu with error checking

Tags: function, batch-file, menu

Ok So I have written this script and it works but I have cheated it and done some dogy Functions for the error checking. After checking command out there I cannot find anything that I can get to work to check if the :Opt function exists.

```
@echo off

Echo Below are a list of options please select one. Mulople options can 
Echo be entered provided that they are seperated by a spaceor comma (,) 
Echo eg. 1,2,3 1 or 1 2 3
Echo Available Options:
Echo Option 1 
Echo Option 2
Echo Option 3

SET /P Selection=Please enter Option? 
SET String=%Selection%
echo You have chosen: %Selection% 

Call :ErrorChecker
Echo Options have been Varified
Call :Process
pause

goto :EOF

:ErrorChecker
Rem This is an error checker to check if a Function exists this does not actually check the :Opt function but each 
Rem :Exist Function there for each :Opt Function must have a corresponding :Exist   function or it will not run.
Rem WARRNING Each :Opt Function must have a corresponding Empty :Exist Function or this Script will error.
for %%A in (%Selection%) do (
Call :Exist%%A 2>NUL
if errorlevel 1 (
SET /P Selection= There where errors in the Selection %String%, Please choose Valid                   
Options:
goto :ErrorChecker
)
)
goto :EOF

:Process
Echo !STARTING RESTORE!
for %%A in (%Selection%) do (
Call :Opt%%A
)
GOTO :EOF

:Exist1
Rem this is apart of error checker and corresponds to the :opt Function below.
Rem !!!DO NOT PLACE CODE HERE!!!
exit /B 0
:Opt1
ECHO Option 1's code
exit /B 0

:Exist2
Rem this is apart of error checker and corresponds to the :opt Function below.
Rem !!!DO NOT PLACE CODE HERE!!!
exit /B 0
:Opt2
ECHO Option 2's code
exit /B 0

:Exist3
Rem this is apart of error checker and corresponds to the :opt Function below.
Rem !!!DO NOT PLACE CODE HERE!!!
exit /B 0
:Opt3
ECHO Option 3's code
exit /B 0
```

I know there are some dodgy things in but it dose works.

Comment: And you want the code to do...

Comment: It's just the error checking is dodgy it is not actually checking that the Opt Function exists it is checkeckin if a corresponding Exist function exists. 

The Call command is the issue in the ErrorChecker function, I need a way of calling the function without actually running it to check if there is a function.